# Fink Will Not Install

Tags: xcode, fink

Hi I am trying to install Fink on my Mac and I get as far as the ./bootstrap step. When I run it it says

> Checking package... looks good (fink-0.38.5).
>
> Checking system... i386-apple-darwin14.3.0
>
> This system is supported and tested.
>
> Distribution: 10.10
>
> Architecture: x86_64
>
> Checking cc... looks good.
>
> Checking make... looks good.
>
> Checking head... looks good.
>
> Verifying that installed Xcode Command Line Tools version is supported...
>
> 6.3.2.0.1.1431401888 is OK
>
> Verifying that installed Xcode app version is supported...
>
> Found Xcode version: 6.3.2
>
> ERROR:  This version of fink needs at most Xcode 6.2 on this OS X version.

I'm not exactly sure what to do or why it is saying this. If someone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is already self-explained.

Your Xcode is too new (oops). Fink-0.38.5 supports Xcode 6.2 or below only.

p.s.

> fink-0.38.5 was released on 14 May, 2016. This release enables official OS X 10.10.3 support, and reverts a change made in fink-0.38.4 to restore the requirement that the /usr/X11R6 convenience symlink be present for the x11* virtual packages to be active. (Source: http://www.finkproject.org/
>   )

well, this version is released in future ?!

Comment: Haha yes I pulled it from the future. Anyways I think I found a workaround. I had version 0.38.4 sitting in my downloads folder and I was able to install that! From there I upgraded to 0.38.5. It seems to be running fine so far. Perhaps that will be helpful to someone who had the same problem

Comment: You can put this as answer :)